# How to substract one day in ical.Net nuget

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, icalendar

I am using library ical.NET for parsing some online ical calendars and previewing into my webapp.

for example:

```
airBnbCalendar = client.DownloadData(Constants.Constants.airbnbGoldAptCalendarUri);
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(airBnbCalendar);
airBnbCal = Ical.Net.Calendar.Load(stream);

foreach (var item in airBnbCal.Events.Where(m => m.End.Date >= DateTime.Now))
{
 resposneCalendarModel.Add(new ResponseCalendarModel
 {
   CheckInDateTime = item.Start.Date,
   //I want CheckOutDateTime to substract one day before based on CheckOutDateTime
   CheckOutDateTime = item.End.Date - item.End.Date.AddDays(-1),
   // with these item.End.AddDays(-1) 
   //I am getting an error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.TimeSpan' to 'System.DateTime'
   Duration = item.Duration.Days
 });
}
```

How to convert it to TimeSpan?

Is this right thing to do:

```
CheckOutDateTime = item.End.Date - new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Try this ...    CheckOutDateTime = item.End.Date.AddDays(-1),

Comment: how your ResponseCalendarModel class looks like? Duration DateTime or TimeSpan?

Comment: @DaveClough answer is correct

Comment: @DaveClough your answer is pointless because I explicitly wrote same codeline wich not works.

Comment: @MihirDave DateTime..I managed this just putting checkOutDate = checkOutDate  - new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0) just wondering is there more elegant solution